# How to make mono copy data files into subdirectory the same way visual studio does

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I have a C# project which references a shared project.  The shared project includes a lot of data I want copied in a folder, e.g.

```
Data/file1.txt
```

When built with visual studio, all the files move over to the output directory with a subfolder, e.g.

```
bin/Release/Data/file1.txt
```

but on mono, it ignores the subdirectory, e.g.

```
bin/Release/file1.txt
```

How can I force mono to maintain the same directory structure during the build?

As an update, during the build I see the following as well:

```
Target _CopyDeployFilesToOutputDirectoryPreserveNewest:
    Copying file from 'Data/file1.txt' to 'bin/Release/file1.txt'
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE : This appears to be a bug in Xamarian Studio 5.9.4. Shared projects with items flagged as Copy to Output Directory will not respect the directory structure that they have in the Project...

Assuming:

- MonoDevelop / Xamarian Studio 5.9.x+
- Project is flagged to **use MSBuild** in the Project Options / Build / General panel
- Project is a .shproj (bug, other project types are ok)

Set the File Properties to:

- Copy to Output Directory

[image]

Build and you should have:

```
.
├── AGenericFile.txt
├── Data
│   ├── Data2
│   │   └── file2.txt
│   ├── SharedData.txt
│   └── file1.txt
├── Data2
│   └── file3.txt
├── foodata.exe
└── foodata.exe.mdb
```

If you are still having problems, look at your project xml and make sure that your have a

```
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
```

set on each of those data files.

Project / Tools / Edit file:

```
~~~
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Data\Data2\" />
    <Folder Include="Data2\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="AGenericFile.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Data\file1.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Data\Data2\file2.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Data2\file3.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
~~~
```

Comment: I seem to have all of that set but it still isn't working.  The one major difference though is that this project is a shared project, and so doesn't have a .csproj, but a .shproj file, which does not have an MSBuild option (or really any others).  It does contain XML which looks exactly like your sample though.  Perhaps this is a bug with shared projects?

Comment: Interesting. Xam Studio/MonoDevelop is using their own version of MSBuild that runs against the proj xml file (like VS, but it is not 100% the same....). I would 1) Post on Xamarin's forums with the shproj info and/or open a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) 2) Try to use an EXEC statement to copy those files or  use a custom post-build command to do it manually for now.. :-/

Comment: Thanks much for the help! Will be using a rather gross cp command for now.

Comment: Awesome! This would be great, but does this mean all this data will get embedded into the assembly with visual studio?

Comment: Sorry, not enough sleep. You are correct, that is not a solution. Back to that cp script I guess. :-/